# Choosing $N$ so that the sum is greater than 10

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

I have to find a number $N$ such that the sum

$$\sum_{n=3}^N \dfrac{1}{n(\log_2 n)(\log_2\log_2 n)} > 10.$$

I know that the series
$$\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{n(\log_2 n)(\log_2\log_2 n)}$$
diverges by using the Cauchy Condensation Test. However, it diverges very slowly. For example, when I take $N=100$, the sum is even less than 1.

So, I don't know how to find the number $N$ such that the sum is greater than 10.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Your sequence is not defined at $n=1$, what term do you start at?

Comment: Sorry, it starts at $n=3$.

Comment: I would solve $\log{\log{\log{N}}}>10$ for $N$. Test the sum form $N=3$ to $N\geq e^{e^{e^{10}}}$.

Comment: @Medo: I have a question. Why do we need to find $N$ such that $\log \log N > 10$?

Comment: How are you computing it?  It will take a *lot* of terms so the numeric accuracy is a challenge.  Is it true that you just want an $N$ that is big enough, with no penalty for being too big?

Comment: We know this sum is about $\log_2 \log_2 \log_2 N$, so $2^{2^{2^{10}}}\approx 5.4 \cdot 10^{307}$ is a reasonable guess.  If you just need $N$ large enough, I would raise $2$ or $10$ to this power and claim victory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your function is monotonically decreasing, we know that
$$
\int_3^N\frac{1}{x\log_2(x)\log_2\log_2(x)}dx < \sum_{n=3}^N \frac{1}{x\log_2(x)\log_2\log_2(x)}
$$
This integral can be evaluated
$$
\int_3^N\frac{1}{x\log_2(x)\log_2\log_2(x)}dx = \log(2)^2\log_2(\log_2(\log_2(x)))|_3^N
$$
We want to find $N$ such that
$$
\log(2)^2\log_2(\log_2(\log_2(N)))-\log(2)^2\log_2(\log_2(\log_2(3)))>10
$$

And now from here you can play around with the inequality and algebra to get a bound for $N$

Comment: I understand but how can we do if we are not allowed to use integral?

Comment: If you make each term in the sum a box with height the value of the term and width $1$ the integral is a smooth curve that goes through all the points and (because the function is decreasing) shaves a tiny bit off the top of the rectangle.  That justifies that the integral is less than the sum.  Why don't you want to use it?

Comment: This result is cute  $\sum_{n=1}^{2^k} \frac 1n \ge 1 + \frac k2$ so $\sum_{n=1}^{2^{18}} \frac 1n \ge 10$.  Try to find a series of integers $n_j$ so that $j < n_j \log_2 n_j \log_2 \log_2 n_j$.

Comment: .... then $\sum_{m=1}^{n_{2^{18}}} \frac 1{m\log_2 m \log_2\log_2 m} >\sum_{m=1;=n_j\text{for some }j}^{n_{2^{18}}} \frac 1{m\log_2 m \log_2\log_2 m}>\sum_{m=1;=n_j\text{for some }j}^{n_{2^{18}}} \frac 1{j}= \sum_{j=1}^{2^{18}}\frac 1j > 10$.

Comment: @fleablood If $j < n_j \log_2 n_j \log_2 \log_2 n_j$ then $\frac{1}{j} > \dfrac{1}{n_j \log_2 n_j \log_2 \log_2 n_j}$. And your argument is not correct.

Comment: @RossMillikan Because I haven't study about Riemann Integral so I cannot use it to solve that problem.

Comment: @FactorY that was typo/toggle miscount.  So find a $n_j$ so that $j > n_j yadda yadda$.  It's not a big deal.  Notice in my answer I corrected that.

Answer (score 3):

This may be overkill (you don't need to find the *least* $N$ do you?)

The harmonic series is know to diverge and we can find and $M$ so that $\sum_{j=1}^M \frac 1j > 10$.  One such formula is $\sum_{j=1}^{2^k} \frac 1j > 1+\frac k2$ so $\sum_{j=1}^{2^{18}} \frac 1j > 1 +\frac{18}2=10$ but you can maybe find another formula.

Now $a_n= n\log_2 n \log_2\log_2 n$ is increasing but very slowly.  I think it is a safe but and probably easy to show that $a_{k+1} -a_k < 1$.

Therefore there is a series of indexes, $k_1, k_2, k_3,......$ where $a_{k_1} < 1 <a_{k_2}$ and $a_{k_j} < j < a_{k_{j+1}}$

Example $a_3 = 3\log_2 3\log_2 \log_2 3 < 1$ so we can say $k_1 =3$ and if $m$ is such that $1 < m\log_2 m \log_2 \log_2 m < 2$ we can set $k_2 = m$ and so on.

Now $\sum_{n=3}^M \frac 1{a_n} < \sum_{n=k_i; i=1}^{k_W: k_W\le M; k_{W+1}>M} \frac 1{a_{k_i}}>\sum_{n=k_i;i=1}^{k_W} \frac 1i = \sum_{i=1}^W \frac 1i$.

So to solve $\sum_{n=3}^M \frac 1{a_n} > 10$ it suffices to solve for $W$ so $\sum_{i=1}^W\frac 1i > 10$.  We can solve that with $W = 2^{18}$

Then we need find a $k_W$ so that $2^{18} -1 < k_W \log_2 k_W \log_2 \log_2 k_W < 2^{18}$.  And that can be our value of $M$.

===

Okay, overkill.

For $n \ge 3$ we know $0< \log_2 \log_2 n < \log_2 n < n$ so $n\log_2 n \log_2 \log_2 n > (\log_2 \log_2 n)^3$ and $(\log_2 \log_2 n)^3\ge 2^{18}$ if $\log_2 \log_2 n \ge 2^6$ which is true if $\log_2 n \ge 2^{2^6}$ which is true if $n \ge 2^{2^{2^6}}$.

So consider $\sum_{k=3}^{2^{2^{2^6}}} \frac 1{k\log_2 k \log_2 \log_2 k} > \sum_{k=3}^{2^{2^{2^6}}} \frac 1{(\log_2 \log_2 k)^3} > \sum_{k=3}^{2^{2^{2^6}}} \frac 1{\lceil (\log_2\log_2 k)^3\rceil} \le$
$\sum_{k\in A} \frac 1{\lceil (\log_2\log_2 k)^3\rceil}$

We $A$ is any subset of $\{3,...., 2^{2^{2^6}}\}$

Now we can find a subset of $\{3,...., 2^{2^{2^6}}\}$ so that $A= \{a_1,a_2, ....., a_{2^{18}}\}$ where $\lceil (\log_2\log_2 a_j)^3 \rceil = j$ (Let's put a pin in that for now)

So $\sum_{k=3}^{2^{2^{2^6}}} \frac 1{k\log_2 k \log_2 \log_2 k} >$
$\sum_{a_j\in A}\frac 1{\lceil (\log_2\log_2 a_j)^3 \rceil} =\sum_{a_j\in A}\frac 1{j}=$
$\sum_{j=1}^{2^{18}} \frac 1j \ge 1 + \frac {18}2 = 10$.

Ta-da.....

All that remains is our pin.  $0 =\log_2 \log_2 2 < \log_2\log_2 3 < \log_2\log_2 4=1$ so $0 < (\log_2\log_2 3)^3 < 1$ and so $\lceil  (\log_2\log_2 3)^3 \rceil = 1$ and so let $a_1 = 3$.

Now $(\log_2 \log_2 (n+1))^3 - (\log_2\log_2 n)^3 < 1$ (another pin) so for every $K$ there is an $n$ so that $K-1 <  (\log_2\log_2 n)^3  \le K$ so we can in such a case set $a_K = $ that $n$.  And as $(\log_2 \log_2 2^{2^{2^6}})^3 = 2^{18}$ we can set $a_{2^{18}} = 2^{2^{2^6}}$.

... guess the only thing left is to prove $(\log_2 \log_2 (n+1))^3 - (\log_2\log_2 n)^3 < 1$ for all $n$....

Comment: $a_3 = 3\log_2 3\log_2 \log_2 3$ is not less than 1. It is about $3.15937$.

Comment: Moreover, you can never find such sequence like this.

Comment: Hmm.... I was worried a little about that. ... But that's not a big a deal.  So we have to make up a $1 + \frac 12 +\frac 13$.  SO we need $\sum_{n=1}^{2^k} \frac 1n \ge 1 +\frac k2 \ge 10 + 1+\frac 12 +\frac 13$ so $k>2\times 9\frac 56 =20$.  So do this all but for $2^{20}$ and all will work.

Comment: "you can never find such sequence like this" Course you can. Although we have to offset the start.  We just need $\frac {d((\log_2 x)^3)}{dx} < x$.  Then for $n > x$ we have.  We start our sequence there.